# Arquivo supostamente sendo usado não pode ser apagado

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, log

Tenho um software que registra logs de erros dele mesmo dentro de uma pasta "logs". Cada arquivo de log é criado com a data do dia atual, sendo assim exclusivo para o dia atual. Exemplo: *30-04-2014.log*.

Eu uso `StreamWriter` para registrar os logs cada vez que eles ocorrem. O programa **não** é um serviço, portanto ele não "vira o dia" rodando na máquina. Desconsiderem que o meu `StreamWriter` possa estar usando os arquivos de dias anteriores (os quais eu desejo apagar).

O programa tem um timer que roda o seguinte método a cada 1 hora para apagar meus logs de dias anteriores:

```
public static void LimparLogsAntigos()
{
  //Suponha que eu tenha permissão total para gravar em "C:\logs".
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\logs", "*.log", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

  foreach (string file in files)
  {
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
    if (fi.LastWriteTime.DayOfYear <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayOfYear) //Apagar somente logs do dia anterior.
     {
        fi.Delete();
     }
  }
}
```

Utilizando este código, eu recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> System.IO.IOException: O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'C:\logs\23-04-2014.log' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo. em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Daí a cada hora eu fico acumulando erros e os logs antigos não são apagados.

Alguma parte desse código bloqueia arquivos contra acesso?
`FileInfo` é a melhor forma de acessar as datas de último acesso ou escrita no arquivo?

**EDIÇÃO:**

Esqueci de mencionar um detalhe: é possível apagar (e qualquer outra operação) os arquivos usando o explorer.

**EDIÇÃO:**

Para registrar os erros, eu chamo o seguinte método dentro do `catch`:

```
public static void RegErro(string msgErro) //recebe a mensagem de erro a ser registrada no log.
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logsFolder + "\\" + logName, true, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.Write(msgErro);
        sw.Close();
        File.SetAttributes(logsFolder + "\\" + logName, FileAttributes.Normal | FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed);
    }
```

Comment: poste um resumo de como vc cria o .log, acredito que o problema esteja no modo de criar e não no deletar.

Answer (score 2):

Nossa, consegui descobrir o problema! A culpa foi minha, pois não mencionei que, antes de deletar os logs antigos, eu verifico se há logs maiores que 2KB (o que significa que houveram muitos erros naquele dia), para enviá-los por e-mail.

O problema veio justamente da parte de enviar os logs, pois eu não sabia que deveria descartar (*Dispose*) o objeto que eu criei com a classe `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`.
Depois que eu simplesmente botei tudo dentro do `using`, o programa inteiro funcionou corretamente e os arquivos não ficaram mais em uso "misteriosamente".

**Antes:**

```
private EnviarEmail()
{
  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

**Depois:**

```
private EnviarEmail()
{
  using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

Espero que meu erro tenha sido útil.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se seu método que cria os arquivos de logs estão os criando com permissão de acesso  e se ao colocar o ponteiro no inicio do arquivo na criação você também precisar fechar.

```
   StreamWriter sw = new StreamReader(fs);
   //Algum código aqui
   sw.Close();
```

Uma vez que você não o fecha o arquivo fica aberto logo em uso.

Comment: Neste seu exemplo, pode acontecer exatamente o oposto. Se houver uma exceção, o arquivo não vai ser fechado.

Comment: Sim, eu fecho o StreamWriter ao final de cada relato de erro. A grande questão é: há logs de outros dias que o programa alega estarem sendo usados. Isso soa como uma piada para mim, já quem nenhuma parte do meu código grava nem lê nada de arquivos de dias anteriores, com exceção do FileInfo, que, da forma que eu usei, não era para bloquear nenhum arquivo.

Comment: Teria sido melhor com um using: `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamReader(fs)) { /* código aqui */ }`